# Drawing picture in circle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to draw the picture of 4 players in circles, I am creating a turn based cards game. currently I am drawing the picture like as follows.

```
GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect(playerPos[ID].x, playerPos[ID].y, 100, 70), (Texture2D)Resources.Load ("gambler", typeof(Texture2D)));
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to round the shape of the window in which players photo will be shown.

Comment: You Can use mask Shader also for drawing the cricle in unity

Answer (score 0):

In windows application draw oval i.e circle and set player image as background and assign background image layout to stretch

Answer (score 0):

What you need is masking your image, sadly there is no functions to do that via fw (at least not without using WPF), so you should do it manually.

You can do it via getpixel/setpixel or through LockBits and manually modifying the bitmap data, I will show you here how to do it with get/setpixel for ease of understanding.

Given your user's image and having a bitmap with a circle drawn in it with alpha channel and having the same size as the user's image, you can transfer the alpha from your mask to your image:

```
       //plyImage is a Bitmap with player's image, maskImage is a bitmap with the circle mask

       for (int y = 0; y < plyImage.Height; y++)
        {

            for (int x = 0; x < plyImage.Width; x++)
            {

                Color srcColor = plyImage.GetPixel(x, y);
                Color maskColor = maskImage.GetPixel(x, y);
                Color finalColor = Color.FromArgb(maskColor.A, srcColor.R, srcColor.G, srcColor.B);
                plyImage.SetPixel(x, y, finalColor);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Its mean no other channel than masking can be used. Ok thanks a lot gonna do with that.

Comment: Well I only masked the alpha to achieve what you asked, but you can mask as you wish with this method.

Comment: Also, don't use that code in production, is terribly slow, to get fast results do the same but with LockBits

Comment: Yup i got some idea from your logic. Hopefully I will achieve the target now.

Comment: Oky but for that I have to do some r&d on LockBits 1st. :)

Comment: Yes, but it will be worth it, with LockBits you access raw pixel data as a pointer, so accessing and modifying is as fast as it can be.

Answer (score 0):

From your tags, it looks like you are trying to achieve this in Unity. As Gusman said, you'll need a mask to do this. However, in Unity, you would achieve this using a shader and not directly changing an image's pixels.

There is an example in the Unity wiki: [Texture Mask](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Texture_Mask)

You can also download an example from this thread: [Draw Texture + TextureMask](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/54301-DrawTexture-TextureMask-circular-minimap-with-offset)